# How can I translate the expression "Got it!" in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

How can I say "Got it!" in Italian? Google Translate gives "Fatto!" and "Ce l'ho!", but I think these are not correct answers.

Comment: `Do you have the first number of Batman comic? Yes, I've got it!` translates in `Hai il primo numero del fumetto di Batman? Si, ce l'ho!`: that's where the google translation cames from, but we know that's [quite wrong](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46230/can-one-answer-have-you-got-with-yes-ive-got).

Comment: Actually, "Ce l'ho!" is used, at least in the north of Italy. Me: "<...long explanation...>" Student (suddenly brightens up): "Ce l'ho"!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would say:

```
Capito!
Tutto chiaro!
```

I am from Italy and I think the best ways to express what "got it" means are those :)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Elisabetta's answer, you could use:

- (Ho) capito (literal translation)
- Ok
- Va bene

What Google Translates says is however wrong and far from the intended meaning.

Answer (score 6):

If you're thinking about something you can't remember and suddenly you got it, you can say "Ce l'ho" too, but it's quite **informal**.

Hope this helps,

FWhite

Comment: I've never heard it -- It must be a regional use.

Comment: I was going to propose the same translation. Quite informal, maybe regional (I am from Romagna and for me this exclamation is quite usual, so I don't know if it is well known elsewhere or not), but to me "Ce l'ho!" expresses the same feeling of achievement that can be found in "Got it!"

Comment: Yep, "ce l'ho" is quite common, at least in the north. It is very close to "Got it!", even in the sense of "I grasped the concept" ("Ho afferrato il concetto!")

Comment: I am from the north but I never hear it... For me it's more common "ci sono!"

Answer (score 6):

In the context of understanding something, "capito!" is the correct translation. By the way, etymologically it means "got it!"

"Ce l'ho" doesn't mean anything in that context and only applies to having (got) an object.

Comment: Grazie Charo :)

Comment: "Ce l'ho" sounds to me like a simple Anglicism and I've never heard it (Tuscany, Liguria, Lombardy and Friuli Venezia Giulia).  Like, for instance "realizzare" (to realize) to intend "rendersi conto", which - I'm sorry to say - I hear quite often.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context.

"Ce l'ho" may be correct, as in the example from Narmer, if it means that you possess something.

When it means that you understood something, as black and Elisabetta said, you can translate:

```
"OK"
"Capito"
"Chiaro"
"Va bene"
```

In the latter case the use of "Ce l'ho" is quite uncommon...

Comment: `Ce l'ho may be correct, if it means that you possess something.` Actually, "Got it" can be translated as "Ce l'ho", meaning "Got an idea!". It's quite common in italian.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it highly depends on the meaning, and when it means that you understood something, especially if it's not said in response to a question but after doing some thinking - in my opinion the best translation is "Ci sono!" ("I'm there / I got there!") as suggested by @laika because it is of common use and it is as informal as "I got it!".
I'm from the north as well (Emilia Romagna) but "Ce l'ho!" in my experience is not common at all, personally I believe it's regional.